# How to use SNAT with firewalld (vs MASQ)

Tags: firewalld

I have an Fedora 26 server I use as a gateway/router (Along with other things)
2 NIC's and a static external IP

I am used to iptables and I use SNAT vs MASQ

I have done a good bit of searching for how to use SNAT with firewalld - but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use **direct options**:

> ```
> [--permanent] --direct --add-rule { ipv4 | ipv6 | eb } table chain priority args
> ```
>
> Add a rule with the arguments args to chain chain in table table with
>   priority priority.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule NAT POSTROUTING  0 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 1.2.3.4
```

or

> ```
> --direct --passthrough { ipv4 | ipv6 | eb } args
> ```
>
> Pass a command through to the firewall. args can be all iptables,
>   ip6tables and ebtables command line arguments. This command is
>   untracked, which means that firewalld is not able to provide
>   information about this command later on, also not a listing of the
>   untracked passthoughs.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 1.2.3.4
```